# Как вызвать функцию, а в качестве параметров передать элементы массива?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

Люди, помогите! У меня есть массив с несколькими значениями, и есть функция, которая принимает определенное количество переменных, но сколько - неизвестно. Например,

```
array = ['val_1', 'val_2']
def function(val_1, val_2):
    pass
```

А нужно сделать вот что: если количество элементов массива соответствует количеству параметров функции, то надо вызвать эту функцию, а в качестве параметров передать элементы массива. Именно его **элементы**, а не сам массив. А как это сделать? Меня именно интересует, как разложить массив на отдельные переменные и вызвать эту функцию, ведь **размер массива нам неизвестен, как и количество параметров функции.** То есть вариант ниже не подойдет.

```
function(array[0], array[1])
```

Comment: `function(*array)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте `*args`:

```
In [9]: list_ = [1, 2, 3, 4 ,5]

In [10]: def foo(*args):
    ...:     return args
    ...:

In [11]: foo(*list_)
Out[11]: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Если нужно точное соответствие по кол-ву параметров:

```
In [18]: def foo(a, b, c):
    ...:     pass
    ...:

In [19]: if len(list_) == foo.__code__.co_argcount:
    ...:     foo(*list_)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Очень помогли!

Comment: @lleballex отметьте ответ как решение галочкой.

Answer (score 2):

```
def func(*args) :
        pass
m = [1,2,3]
func(*m)
```

Внутри функции через *args* уже обращайтесь к значениям

Comment: Большое спасибо!